# Probability of drawing different numbered cards if order doesn't matter?

Tags: probability, permutations

In class, the lecturer told us how to solve a question where we draw five cards and find the probability that none of the numbers on the cards match.

Let A = no cards have the same number

The total number of outcomes is 52 × 51 × 50 × 49 × 48 (52 P 5) while number of outcomes in A is 52 × 48 × 44 × 40 × 36 (13 P 5 × 45)

By dividing these two, you get 0.5071.

I was just wondering, how would this differ if order **did not** matter? Would you perhaps divide by 5 to take into account the repeats? The lecturer said the answer would surprise us but then did not give the answer so I was hoping to get it from here.

Comment: **Possible typo alert**.  You probably intended that $52 \times \cdots \times 36 = 13P5 \times 4^5.$  Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format your math.

Comment: Re the question that you asked, what is your thinking?  What happens if you experiment with 2 card hands, instead of 5 card hands?  What about 3 card hands?  Please see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) which discusses how to ask a good question on mathSE.

Comment: The fact that the order doesn't matter is true for both numerator and denominator, so its effect cancels.